# Handling events and accessing bound values in polymer paper-input -- is this a good pattern?

Tags: events, button, data-binding, polymer

My question is whether the following is a good pattern for Polymer?

The other purpose for my posting is to show how to handle events and access bound values from Polymer elements in the mainline of your html. I couldn't find good examples and it took me some time to get my head around how this should work so hopefully it is of use to others (assuming I have it right!)

I recognize that I could encapsulate the entire handling within a new Polymer element but sometimes this seems a bit awkward.

**Note** if you want try this code you will need to update the references to the Polymer elements.

```
    <!--
    Use the template tag to wrap your Polymer elements with data binding: Will Hopkins
  -->

  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>paper-input</title>

<!--
    Update the following script and links to reflect your Polymer element locations
  -->



  <script src="/polymer/platform/platform.js"></script>

  <link href="/polymer/font-roboto/roboto.html" rel="import">
  <link href="/polymer/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
  <link href="/polymer/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

  <style shim-shadowdom>

  body {
    font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 24px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  }

  paper-input.narrow {
    width: 150px;
  }

  </style>

</head>
<body unresolved>
  <section>
<!--
    OK here is the secret sauce. Wrap your Polymer tags with the template tag, give it and id and specify auto binding
  -->
  <template id="user-maintenance" is="auto-binding">

    <div><paper-input label="ID" floatinglabel=true type=number value="{{iD}}"></paper-input></div>
    <div><paper-input label="First Name" id="firstName" floatinglabel=true value="{{firstName}}"></paper-input></div>
    <div><paper-input label="Last Name" floatinglabel=true value="{{lastName}}"></paper-input></div>
    <div><paper-input label="Blurb" floatinglabel=true multiline maxrows=5 value="{{blurb}}"></paper-input></div>
    <div><paper-input label="Concurrency Control"value="{{conControl}}" disabled></paper-input></div>

    <br>
    <p>id: {{iD}}, First Name: {{firstName}}, Last Name: {{lastName}}, Blurb: {{blurb}}, Concurrency Control: {{conControl}}</p>
    <div>
      <paper-button raised id="createButton" on-tap="{{createClicked}}">Create</paper-button>
      <paper-button raised id="retrieveButton" on-tap="{{retrieveClicked}}">Retrieve</paper-button>
      <paper-button raised id="updateButton" on-tap="{{updateClicked}}">Update</paper-button>
      <paper-button raised id="deleteButton" on-tap="{{deleteClicked}}">Delete</paper-button>
    </div>
  </template>

</section>

<script>

    //
    // OK now lets get a handle to our template
    //
    var inlineBinding = document.getElementById('user-maintenance');

    // now we can set an input value

    inlineBinding.conControl = 13;

    // and handle events

    inlineBinding.createClicked = function() {

    // and retrieve values

    alert("Create fired for: " + inlineBinding.firstName + " " + inlineBinding.lastName);
  };
  inlineBinding.retrieveClicked = function() {
    alert("Retrieve fired for: " + inlineBinding.firstName + " " + inlineBinding.lastName);
  };
  inlineBinding.updateClicked = function() {
    alert("Update fired for: " + inlineBinding.firstName + " " + inlineBinding.lastName);
  };
  inlineBinding.deleteClicked = function() {
    alert("Delete fired for: " + inlineBinding.firstName + " " + inlineBinding.lastName);
  };

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine and something we show off in the docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside

`<template is="auto-binding">` is in fact a custom element :), so you shouldn't shy away from it. The only thing it doesn't do (compared to `<polymer-element>` is `<prop>Changed()` handlers).